# Is there a way to fix Salesforce Email nesting?

Tags: email, email-template, html

I'm part of an organization that just recently moved over to Salesforce from a previous ticketing system. Since doing so, we've had problems with the readability of email communiques between Support Technicians and Customers.

Specifically, where our email conversations were previously:

---

BEGIN EMAIL:

3 Second tech reply

2 First customer reply

1 First tech reply

END EMAIL

---

Now they're:

---

BEGIN EMAIL:

3 Second tech reply

> > 2 First customer reply
> >
> > > > 1 First tech reply
> > > >         2 First customer reply
> > > >         First tech reply

1 First tech reply

END EMAIL

---

So, basically everything is getting nested and it looks awful. And after you get to about 5 back-and-forths with everyone's signatures in there, the email becomes unreadable. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe theres a way to customize this outside of code.

**Option 1**

Are you using the built in email handler or a custom one?

[Custom Email handlers](http://sforcehacks.blogspot.com/2012/01/email-to-case-custom-email-handler.html)

If you make a custom handler you'll be able to adjust the body of the email message prior to inserting the record.

**Option 2**

You can make a Visualforce widget to take the place of the related list and provide your own logic for displaying the messages. This may be a bit preferable to creating a custom email handler in terms of the amount of work it will take.

[Embedding VF Pages in the page layout.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005105&language=en_US)

Then simply parse the body and reformat it.

**Option 3**

If you don't want to do a code based solution, you can simply train people to chop off the email chain prior to replying to the customer as that will minimize the number of levels maintained in the email.

**Addendum**

I will add that what you're describing is the default behavior of many email applications such as Google mail. It's not an uncommon way to represent email reply chains. I'm sure that this is the last thing you want to tell your customers but it may just be a matter of them learning to adapt to this new display (deal with it).